# What is the parameter Alpha in Ridge Regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Can someone give me an understandable explanation of the parameter `Alpha` in SKlearn's [Ridge Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)? How does it influence the function etc.? 
Examples would be helpful :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [ask]

Comment: @Dan Your question is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ridge regression minimizes the objective function:
`||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||^2_2`

This model solves a regression model where the loss function is the linear least squares function and regularization is given by the l2-norm. In simple words, `alpha` is a parameter of how much should ridge regression tries to **prevent overfitting**!

Let say you have three parameter `W = [w1, w2, w3]`. In overfitting situation, the loss function can fit a model with `W=[0.95, 0.001, 0.0004]` which means it is highly biased to the first parameter. However, `alpha * ||w||^2_2` increases the loss function in those cases and tries to keep all parameters in some sort of boundaries to prevent overfitting. For instance, with a regularizer, the `W` could be `W=[0.5, 0.2, 0.33]`. When you increase `alpha` you are pushing the Ridge regression to be more robust against overfitting, but might be getting larger training error.

Comment: But how does it affect the function mathematically? I do not really understand your function object.

Comment: @Dan That `||w||^2_2` sum up the power 2 for each `[w1,w2,...]` in this example and add it to the loss function. Optimizer tries to minimize the loss function. Power of 2 makes large parameters adding a large loss to the total lost function.

Comment: @Dan For example `||w||^2_2` for the first example is `sqrt(0.95*0.95 + 0.001*0.001 + 0.0004*0.0004)` and for the second one is equal to `sqrt(0.5*0.5 + 0.2*0.2 + 0.33*0.33)`